# http://sub.site.com is incorrectly redirecting to http://www.sub.site.com instead of https://sub.site.com

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting, virtualhost

Using Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04.2

I have blog.ryangiglio.com set up as a virtualhost. I used the letsencrypt certbot to generate an SSL cert for the server, and set it to force redirects from http://blog.ryangiglio.com to https://blog.ryangiglio.com. When you go directly to https://blog.ryangiglio.com, everything works fine. But if you go to http://blog.ryangiglio.com instead, you get redirected to http://www.blog.ryangiglio.com which doesn't and shouldn't exist.

There is no .htaccess file in the webroot for this domain that could be causing a conflict.

Here is the blog.ryangiglio.com.conf config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName blog.ryangiglio.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/error.log
    # CustomLog /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/access.log combined

  <Directory /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/public_html/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =blog.ryangiglio.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And the blog.ryangiglio.com-le-ssl.conf file generated by certbot

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName blog.ryangiglio.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/error.log
    # CustomLog /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/access.log combined

  <Directory /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/public_html/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.ryangiglio.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.ryangiglio.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

I don't see anything in either of these files that could be causing the error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At least I can tell you that you get redirected with code 301 (=permanent). Normally that's only the case when you told your Apache to do so. I am not entirely sure what %{SERVER_NAME} got filled with, but your rewrite is 'permanent'. I'd try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .? https://blog.ryangiglio.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=301]
```

R=301 and R=permanent is the same, order of parameters doesn't matter.

Comment: The first still seems to redirect to www.blog.ryangiglio.com. The second isn't performing a redirect at all and just displays the document root.

Comment: 1) So 'Servername' seems to include the 'www.'
2) blog.ryangiglio.com should only be rewrited to https://blog.ryangiglio.com with the same URI the initial request had. Thought that was your request...

Eventually you can elaborate on what you want to call, what your expected result is and what you get instead.

Comment: 1) Can you think of a reason SERVER_NAME would include the www? 2) Sorry if I wasn't clear - for the second option you gave it was staying at http and displaying the website instead of sending you to https

Comment: 1) nope, I can't. Just seemed like it. Also can't find anything that points towards such behaviour.
2) Do me a favor and try this (see edit)

Comment: This is an incredibly hard thing to debug because of the browser caching, but it seems like the second is STILL including the www somehow? I've left it live for the moment so you can see for yourself. (EDIT) No actually, I don't think so - I think it's just staying on the http and displaying...a totally unrelated virtualhost which is another very weird behavior

Comment: the result is pretty much 'DAFUQ' & kinda 'WTF' :D did you try calling https://www.blog.ryangiglio.com and www.blog.ryangiglio.com and the correct one: https://blog.ryangiglio.com ??? Each call gives me another blog...Is that supposed to happen? I mean, are there 2-3+ sites on this webserver or in this config? But I see, what you meant...Seems like the rewrite isn't even tested and thus not applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139614/discussion-between-ryan-giglio-and-hello-fishy).

Comment: just in case you didn't see it: added a lot of stuff in our chat :D